# Access Xaml element attributes through Javascript

Tags: javascript, silverlight, xaml

(Again, a Xaml question. Our teacher isn't very useful unfortunately...)

I have following elements in a xaml file:

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TitleText}" x:Name="InformationGainTextBlock" />
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TitleText}" x:Name="NGramTextBlock" />
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TitleText}" x:Name="PositionTextBlock" />
```

I also have 200 line elements, containing data, like this:

```
<Line Name="Data0" Stroke="Maroon" StrokeThickness="1" X1="154" Y1="123" X2="154" Y2="549" MouseEnter="onMouseEnter" MouseLeave="onMouseLeave" Tag="0.0427409|e l i j k|1" />
```

Now, the idea is that, in the onMouseEnter function (in a javascript file), I extract data from the "Tag" attribute and put it as text in the textblocks. In this example:

```
0.0427409|e l i j k|1
```

So, I have to put '0.0427409' in the InformationGainTextBlock, 'e l i j k' in the NGramTextBlock and '1' in the PositionTextBlock. I also have to change the line colour.

How am I able to do this? I think I've got the pseudocode about right, but not the exact implementation:

```
onMouseEnter(sender, args) {

var data = sender.getAttribute("Tag").Text;
var array[] = data.Split("|");

sender.getElementByName("InformationGainTextBlock").text = array[0];
sender.getElementByName("NGramTextBlock").text = array[1];
sender.getElementByName("PositionTextBlock").text = array[2];
sender.getAttribute("Stroke").text = "Red";
}
```

The onMouseLeave event resets everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
function onMouseEnter(sender, mouseEventArgs) {
  var text = sender["Tag"];
  var array = new Array();
  array = text.split("|");
  sender["Stroke"] = "Red";
  sender.findName("InformationGainTextBlock").text = array[0];
  sender.findName("NGramTextBlock").text = array[1];
  sender.findName("PositionTextBlock").text = array[2];
}
```

What you had was very close :)